PC immediately restarting after shutdown after enabling WoL/WoPCIe
I've been wanting to try WoL to start my PC from outside my network so I enabled "Resume on PCIe" in my BIOS today. After this, whenever I shutdown/hibernate the PC immediately restarts.
I know it's not from any peripherals because it even happens when everything but the power cord is unplugged.
Things I've tried:
Updating Windows
Updating BIOS
Looking at Event Viewer (Source: Unknown for the powering up)
Disabling Resume on PCIe returns the PC to normal behaviour.
Specs:
Windows 10
MSI A520M-A PRO
Ryzen 5 5600
32 GB RAM
Radeon RX 6750XT
See solution below

what are the wake on * settings for the ethernet device?

Unplug your printer

I don't have a printer.
If you're asking what should be able to wake my pc this is the list of wake armed devices:
HID Keyboard Device (005)
HID-compliant mouse (007)
HID Keyboard Device (008)
Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller #2
All of which have been unplugged at some point but the pc still restarted.
If you're asking about the bios setting: I only have a checkmark and its for Resume on PCIe.

The only thing that worked for me, was disabling ERP related settings in the BIOS. Works like a charm now.

Look for service called "TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper" and make sure it's automatic and not stopped, you can find it in computer management inside control panel, also disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP  Right click your network adapter and select Properties then Highlight (TCP/IP)and choose Properties, then Click Advanced Next, go to WINS, and in NetBIOS Settings section select Disable NetBIOS over TCP/IP.


It would be nice to hear a technical justification for this suggestion. Why would this particular network protocol setting affect the PCIe bus[ses]? Does this answer assume that the system in question has a PCIe-connected NIC?

Tried this but it didn't work.
